# PowerPC architecture

Tags: architecture, powerpc

I would like to learn PPC so I want to know the best way to learn. It is to compile my own C/C++ code in PowerPC architecture and then see the assembly output of my code. Is this possible on windows 7 OS?

Comment: sure, if you were running NT 3.x or 4.x on a PPC system, or find a PPC emulator for x86 windows...

Answer (score 0):

The answer given to [this question about PowerPC emulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971839/powerpc-emulation-qemu-pearpc-or) is the most appropriate if you want to stay with the idea to develop on Windows, use

- qemu as emulator, getting it from http://lassauge.free.fr/qemu/
- a debian guest / VM, downloading it at http://blog.aurel32.net/153 (this link has updated files)

If you really want to develop on PowerPC, you could also consider buying an evaluation board or a second-hand G3 or G4 based Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I have used GCC targeting PPC architectures using Cygwin on Windows. Most PPC development boards comes with precompiled binaries. GCC can generate Assembly output.

Answer (score 0):

QEMU can emulate PowerPC.

As others have mentioned, you can procure a PPC cross compiler toolchain, and examine the emitted output of C programs. This is a great way to learn assembly language programming for a new architecture.

Also, old PowerPC Macintoshes are sometimes available on the used market for cheap. (less than $100) For example, a G4 IMac runs about $75, and can run Linux. In such a case the native compiler will emit PPC assembly, so no need to deal with cross compiling nor emulation.

Unfortunately, there seem to be no cheap PowerPC single-board computers (SBCs), unlike ARM, where you have the Raspberry Pi at ~$35, among others.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read the assembly, the best way to do this is to use the [GodBolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) on the web rather than on Windows 7. For example, [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Hg4Xxw) is a simple C function compiled with gcc 4.8.5 for PowerPC. Using the Compiler Explorer, you can compare compilers across vendors, architectures, versions and flags.